# Java - Why won't this work?

Tags: java

This is just a simple rock paper scissors game I made with eclipse as a test and I already put one through this website earlier and got some answers but now I've run into a problem where I cannot find a winner?

```
package rockPaperScissors;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String playerChose;
        String computerChose;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to rock paper scissors!");
            System.out.println("Please enter \"rock\", \"paper\", or \"scissors\"");
            Scanner playerChoice = new Scanner (System.in);
            playerChose = playerChoice.nextLine();
            Random computerChoice = new Random();
            int computer = computerChoice.nextInt(3) + 1;

            switch (computer) {
            case 1:
                computerChose = "rock";
                System.out.println("Computer chose rock!");
                break;
            case 2:
                computerChose = "paper";
                System.out.println("Computer chose paper!");
                break;
            case 3:
                computerChose = "scissors";
                System.out.println("Computer chose scissors!");
            }

            computerChose = new String();

            if (playerChose.equals("rock") && computerChose.equals("scissors") || playerChose.equals("paper") && computerChose.equals("rock") || playerChose.equals("scissors") && computerChose.equals("paper")) {
                System.out.println("Player won!");
            }
            if(playerChose.equals(computerChose)) {
                System.out.println("Game tied!");
            }
            if(computerChose.equals("rock") && playerChose.equals("scissors") || computerChose.equals("paper") && playerChose.equals("rock") || computerChose.equals("scissors") && computerChose.equals("paper")) {
                System.out.println("Computer won!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put some parentheses around your conditional statements. There's some operator priority you're probably neglecting.

Comment: This seems like a very complicated way to implement it.  There is not this much logic to the game...

Comment: Also you do `computerChose = new String();` right before you check which erases any value you previously had.

Comment: I just noticed that as you said it.  Good catch

Comment: Because all the possible plays are known at compile time (i.e. ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS) this seems to be to be a great time to use an enum class ... and then extend it into a Rich Enum Type that contains all the logic germane to each constant ... such as the logic to determine if the counter-move was a winner or loser!

Comment: @Brandon this isn't complicated at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tested and works**

Initialize `computerChose` right away, so change

`String computerChose;` to `String computerChose = "";`

and take away the line `computerChose = new String();` because it's setting the `computerChoose` String to an empty String after you initialized it in your switch cases.

Answer (score 0):

Change your initial declaration of `computerChose` (before your `while`) to `String computerChose = "";` and remove the line that reads `computerChose = new String();` (after your `switch`).

Answer (score 0):

After the `while` statement, computerChose is getting reset using `computerChose = newString()`. Hence, none of the conditions being tested in the `if` statements are equating to true.